# Reading end of huge and dynamic file via SFTP from server

Tags: java, sftp

I am trying to find a way to read just end of huge and dynamic log file (like 20-30 lines from end) via SFTP from server and to save the point until where I read, and if I need more lines, to read more from this point upper.

Everything I've tried takes too long time, I've tried to copy this file on machine and after this to read from end using `ReversedLinesFileReader` because this method need the `File` object, when via SFTP you will get only `InputStream`, takes a lot to download file.

Also tried to count lines and to read from n line but also takes too long and throws exception because sometime in this time file is modified. Another way I tried to connect via SSH and used `tail -100` and get the desired result, but just for one time, because next time I will get also new logs, but I need to go upper. Is there a fast way to get the end of file and to save the point and to read more upper of this point later? Any idea?

Comment: I would suggest you create a digest process which splits the monolith log file into small files probably 5000 lines per file and rank/sequence them based on the order you want to access them. This should make your job a bit easy.

Comment: Not really a direct response, but more like a brainstorming and highly dependent on your requirements and infrastructure, but any chance you'd consider introducing [elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) a/o [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) (or some similarly capable tools for a job like this)? You could then use the available API to retrieve the data based on your criteria, eg [date-range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what SFTP library you're using, but the most widely used Java SSH/SFTP library is [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), so I'll assume you're using that.

The [SFTP protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02) has operations to perform random-access I/O on remote files. Unfortunately, the JSch SFTP client doesn't expose the full range of operations. However, it does have versions of the [`get` operation](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#get-java.lang.String-com.jcraft.jsch.SftpProgressMonitor-long-) (for getting a file from the remote server) which permit skipping over the first part of the remote file. You can use one of these operations to read for example the last 10 KB of a file.

Several of the JSch `get` operations return an `InputStream`. You can read the contents of the remote file from the input stream. If you want to access the remote file line-by-line, you can convert it to [`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) using [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

So, a process might do the following:

1. Call [`stat()`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#stat-java.lang.String-) on the remote file to get its size.
2. Figure out where in the file you want to start reading from. You could keep track of where you stopped reading last time, or you could guess based on the amount of data you're willing to download and the expected size in bytes of these last 20-30 lines.
3. Call [`get()`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#get-java.lang.String-com.jcraft.jsch.SftpProgressMonitor-long-) to start reading it.
4. Process data read from the `InputStream` returned by the `get()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to have a kind of rotating log files, possibly with compression.

Hower [**rsync**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) is a unidirectional synchronisation, that can transmit only the changed parts of a file: for a log the new end.

I am not sure whether it works sufficiently performant in your case, and `ssh` is a prerequisite.