# How to read remote file in reversed order line by line while using JSch

Tags: java, inputstream, apache-commons, jsch

I am connecting a remote server by using `jsch` library(SSH connection is a must). I am using `ChannelSftp` class to access remote file. Since the file is so large ( Tomcat's catalina.out) i need to read the log file in reversed order and download x lines to my machine. `ChannelSftp.get` gives me `InputStream` but i couldnt find a way to read it in reverse order without downloading it. I tried to use apache.commons.io jar's `ReversedLinesFileReader` class but it takes `File` class as constructor parameter which forces me to download file.

Any suggestions?

***Edit: Line by line is not possible for my case. I am downloading by size.***

Comment: Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515788/reading-end-of-huge-and-dynamic-file-via-sftp-from-server

Comment: Maybe `InputStream.skip` behaves like a random-access seek/position. Knowing the file size you can then copy the last buffer(s) to implement a `tail`.

Comment: @JoopEggen The `InputStream` returned by `ChannelSftp.get` does not implement the `skip` method. There's `skip` argument of the `ChannelSftp.get` for that, as the answer to the question linked in the comment by @minus shows.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl How to use skip argument without SftpProgressMonitor parameter? What does it actually do?

Comment: @MertSerimer Just pass `null` to `monitor`. For its meaning, check the documentation linked from the answer (it also says, you can use `null`).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thanks. After i skipped to end, how will i get up line by line?

Comment: Did you read the answer to the linked question? You keep asking questions that are answered there already. Check the section *"So, a process might do the following:"*

Comment: @MartinPrikryl "you could guess based on the amount of data you're willing to download and the expected size in bytes of these last 20-30 lines." Do you think is this  EXACTLY the thing i need? How to make sure how many bytes corresponds to how many lines? I can't cut a line in half depending on bytes.

Comment: This is EXACTLY the only thing that is possible to do. Any tool that reads the last lines of a file (including `ReversedLinesFileReader` or `tail` command) has to do the EXACTLY same thing internally. There's no other way to read last lines of a file.

Comment: If you do not know how to implement this, you may want to ask a new more specific question (or edit your current one).